# Regex - stop at the comma in concatenated emails?

Tags: regex, preg-match

If I have:

> me@myemail.com, you@youremail.com

And I only want the first email address, I use:

```
'/([^\s]+@[^\s]+)/s'
```

But if the supplied data has no space like so:

> me@myemail.com,you@youremail.com

My expression gives the whole string. How can I get the first email address in both examples? My fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/rJ6b9n/1

Comment: The pattern is not great. Even if you do have the space, it will match the comma...

Comment: How embarrassing - I didn't notice that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` to indicate that pattern starts with:

`^(([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.-_]+))`

This will only take the first mail.

If you remove `^` it will chose every mail that is into the string

Answer (score 0):

You can add comma and it will find the first ([^\s]+@[^\s]+),

see [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6b9n/2) it will find you email in group 1

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first email address it's enough to add a comma at the end of the regex and get the first group

`([^\s]+@[^\s^]+),`

If you need all the emails you can use this regex with the "global" flag

`[,\s]*([^\s]+@[^\s^]+)[,\s]*`

see https://regex101.com/r/rJ6b9n/4

Answer (score 0):

Since your regex is a capture group, you could do it like this:

([^\s]+@[^\s]+)\,

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do the job:

```
$emails = array(
    'me@myemail.com, you@youremail.com',
    'me@myemail.com,you@youremail.com',
);

// first approch, preg_match
// find email followed by a comma
foreach($emails as $email) {
    preg_match('/\S+@\S+?(?=,)/', $email, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
echo "=======================================================\n";

// second approch, preg_split
foreach($emails as $email) {
    echo preg_split('/,/', $email)[0],"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => me@myemail.com
)
Array
(
    [0] => me@myemail.com
)
=======================================================
me@myemail.com
me@myemail.com
```